# Getting the same value on the entire row with numpy add.at

Tags: python, numpy

My question is the following, for an 2-d array of a length of a couple millions would
np.add.at be faster then a simple iteration over a for?

R would be the 2-d array of values, something like [[17 1], [23, 10] ... ], while nArray is a matrix 25x25 that is initialized with np.zeros, so it contains only 0s (all values in R are between 0 and 24, so there's no errors)

```
for point in R:
    nArray[tuple(point)] += 1
```

The trouble I'm having with np.add.at is that instead of getting the same results, I have the same value on all cells of a row. 
Row 0 -> 35525 35525 ... 35525

Row 1 -> 2078 2078 ... 2078

And this value isnt the same thats on first column on that respective row in the first implementation

```
np.add.at(nArray, R, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [182]: R = np.random.randint(0,25,(100,2)) 

In [197]: A0=np.zeros((25,25),int)                                                                     
In [198]: for point in R: A0[tuple(point)] += 1                                                        
In [199]: A1=np.zeros((25,25),int)                                                                     
In [200]: np.add.at(A1,(R[:,0],R[:,1]),1)                                                              
In [201]: np.allclose(A0,A1)                                                                           
Out[201]: True
```

I used `(R[:,0],R[:,1])` instead of `R` because the docs say:

> If first operand has multiple dimensions, indices can be a
>       tuple of array like index objects or slice objects.

Regarding your `tolist` fix:

```
In [216]: A2=np.zeros((25,25),int)                                                                     
In [217]: np.add.at(A2,R.T.tolist(),1)                                                                 
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`. In the future this will be interpreted as an array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result either in an error or a different result.
  #!/usr/bin/python3
In [218]: np.allclose(A0,A2)                                                                           
Out[218]: True
In [219]: A2=np.zeros((25,25),int)                                                                     
In [220]: np.add.at(A2,tuple(R.T.tolist()),1)                                                          
In [221]: np.allclose(A0,A2)                                                                           
Out[221]: True

In [208]: np.__version__                                                                               
Out[208]: '1.18.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this happens only if R is a numpy array, if it is first converted into a list (for example, by .tolist() ), it works as it's supposed to

Comment: That fix doesn't work for me.  What's your `np.__version__`?  Using `R.T.tolist()` does work, but with a FutureWarning.